# How to make a Graphic overview of Library?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In [Gem: Spreadsheet](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet), there is a [Graphic overview Library](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/spreadsheet.jpeg) in README.md.

This is jpeg is awesome and I want to use it. But I don't know which tool or gem should I use or something related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like generated with widely used **graphviz** toolkit.
I saw some introduction to use it in Ruby [here](http://ruby.about.com/od/tasks/ss/Making-Digraphs-In-Ruby.htm). Proper styles configuration for a particular diagram is a different story.

Hopefuly this answers your question.